# Applying Fast Fourier transform with a specific product function

Tags: algorithm, fft, discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers, dft

**Problem:** Given `2N` degree polynomials as `a0+a1x+a2x2..+aNxN` and
`b0+b1x+b2x2..+bNxN`. Assume no 2 coefficient are the same in the 2 polynomials.

Find the product of the polynomials, the catch is that the product(*) operator between the coefficients is defined differently:

`f(i,j) := ai * bj := 1/abs(ai-bj)`

That means, find the following polynomial:

`c0+c1x+c2x2..+c2Nx2N`,

where

`ck := Σi=0..N f(i,k-i)`

I know that with FFT, 2 polynomials can be multiplied in `O(n lg n)` time with normal product operator between the coefficients but don't have any idea for this kind of problem.

Comment: I would be surprised if there is better than an `O(n^2)` algorithm for this, when you change the product operator like that it destroys a lot of structure of FFT.

Comment: the details of FFT require the "Distributive Property of Multiplication" over addition (i.e, a*b+a*c=a*(b+c)). Since you replace the native multiplication with the "*" operation, the distributive property will not hold. But there might exist some algorithm that takes less than O(N^2).